# How to insert multiple rows using cakePHP

Tags: sql, cakephp

In the cakePHP project I'm building, I want to insert a defined number of identical records. These will serve as placeholders records that will have additional data added later. Each record will insert the IDs taken from two `belongs_to` relationships as well as two other string values.

What I want to do is be able to enter a value for the number of records I want created, which would equate to how many times the data is looped during save.

What I don't know is:

1. how to setup a loop to handle a set number of inserts
2. how to define a form field in cakePHP that only sets the number of records to create.

What I've tried is the following:

```
function  massAdd() {
    $inserts_required = 1;
    while ($inserts_required <= 10) {
        $this->Match->create();
        $this->Match->save($this->data);
        echo $inserts_required++;
    }

    $brackets = $this->Match->Bracket->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('brackets'));
}
```

What happens is:

1. At the top of the screen, above the doc type, the string `12345678910` is displayed, this is displayed on screen
2. A total of 11 records are created, and only the last record has the values passed in the form. I don't know why 11 records as opposed to 10 are created, and why only the last records has the entered form data?

As always, your help and direction is appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of your SQL log?  I just did exactly as you above and I got 10 records properly inserted, with the form data in all of them.  Your sql log should help us figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. in your view try to write something like

   ```
   echo $form->input('Answer.n.title', array('type'=>text'));
   ```

   in controller write

   ```
   function add(){
       $this->Answer->saveAll($this->data);
   }
   ```
2. in my project I used jQuery, to add a new row without reloading a page.

Comment: What I've tried is the following:
function  massAdd() {  
$inserts_required = 1;
while ($inserts_required <= 10) {
$this->Match->create();
$this->Match->save($this->data);
echo $inserts_required++;
}
$brackets = $this->Match->Bracket->find('list');
$this->set(compact('brackets'));
}
What happens is:
1) at the top of the screen, above the doc type, the string 12345678910 is displayed,
2) a total of 11 records are created, and only the last record has the values passed in the form.
I don't know why 11 records as opposed to 10 are created, and why only the last records has the entered form data?

Comment: I don't know why only the 10th record saved, because due to your code, there must be 10 inserted SAME records...
a little tip, before saving just do pr($this->data); and analyze in what format you got your post data.